# How can my wife get the permission to enter into UK?

Tags: united-kingdom, overstay

I am a British citizen and I met a Guatemalean girl. We got married in Great Britain and we had two kids who were born in London and are British as well. Before, she became an overstayed person as her tourist visa expired.

Two years ago, we left UK and now we are living in Ecuador, my first country. So, now we want to go back to UK and get the less complicated permission to enter UK.

What would be the best way to get that permission or visa?

Comment: Just to clarify:  She is only who needs to get the permission to enter into UK.

Comment: Can you clarify: do you want to settle in the UK permanently? Or just visit?

Comment: She wants to settle there permanently, providing that we have got two children with british passports that need to be brought up in England.

Answer (score 5):

1. If she left at her own expense over 2 years ago, overstaying should not be a problem for either a visit or a spouse visa.
2. A "spouse visa" (if you want to live in the UK) requires the British partner to have earnings equivalent to at least £18,600 per year. You might be able to count your overseas earnings, but it can be complicated:

https://www.gov.uk/join-family-in-uk